# Extracting data from array in json data using pyspark

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, expand, json-extract

I am new to pyspark and need some help with trying to extract data within an array. The data is from a form like this [form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlH3E.jpg)The schema is here [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cRYN.png) I have managed to extract data till A1, A2, A3. But unable to extract B1, B2, B3. The path to B1 is Item.Items.L.M.Name.M.B.M.Items.L.M.B1.S

This is the code I am trying to use to extract the data

bitcode = data.select(col('item.guid.s').alias('wID'), col('item.ReportID.s').alias('ReportID'), col('Item.Items.L.M.Name.M.B.M.Items.L.M.B1.S').alias('B1'))
bitcodes.show()

error I get is:
No such struct field B1 in M

Comment: Please share your sample input and output datasets.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.